# READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT not recognized by SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, rowversion

We're running SQL Server 2005 Enterprise SP3, and I'm trying to enable Row Versioning on a new database running in sql server 2005 mode.

Query (against master database):

```
ALTER DATABASE pod-moodle SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Result:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 5, Line 1
'READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT' is not a recognized SET option.
```

Any ideas? I've triple-checked the master database and the pod-moodle database, they are both running in 2005 mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use non-aplhanumeric characters in [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28SQL.90%29.aspx), then you need to delimit with [ and ]

```
ALTER DATABASE [pod-moodle] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```